# Regex and date matching

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search for all possible dates in a string using Regex. 
In my code i have this:

```
String dateSearchPattern = @"(?<Day>\d{2}).(?<Month>\d{2}).(?<Year>\d{4})|(?<Day>\d{2}).(?<Month>\d{2}).(?<Year>\d{2})";

// date format: dd.mm.yyyy or d.m.yyyy or dd.mm.yy or d.m.yy
String searchText = "20.03.2010.25.03.10";

Regex.Matches(searchText, dateSearchPattern); // the matching SHOULD give a count of 2
```

The above code gives only 1 match where it should give 2. Also i need to have a patthern when the date format is like d.m.yyyy or d.m.yy.

Comment: Please provide sample data as well.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern seems perfectly ok. It is giving two match. By any chance have you used the following line to check the count?

```
var match = Regex.Matches(searchText, dateSearchPattern);
Console.WriteLine(match.Count);
```

I used SD 3 on .Net 3.5 (w/o sp1) and your code is giving your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your pattern to this:

```
"(?<Day>\d{1,2}).(?<Month>\d{1,2}).(?:(?<Year>\d{4})|(?<Year>\d{2}))"
```